# Using Text Component On A Primitive Object Causing Scene To Freeze/Lock Up

Tags: html, aframe

In A-Frame 1.1.0 I've noticed that if I took a primitive from A-Frame 1.0.3 that had the text component on it an put it into the new version when the scene loaded in the browser (Chrome in this case), the scene would freeze and the camera could not be moved.
Consider the following:

```html
<a-box text="value: This is some text"></a-box>
```

In version 1.0.3 the scene would render correctly with the text on all sides of the box. However, if you were to run it in 1.1.0 the scene would freeze up. Is this a bug with 1.1.0 or is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the text attribute creates the text inside the element (That would mean the text is invisible as it is inside the cube) based on the **align** attribute that defaults to "left".
The final position can also be affected by the element geometry. In your example, the text would be placed at the center of the "left" side of the cube when facing the front of the text.

I didn't experience anything you describe. Maybe it's something else that causes your issue?

---

In the examples below, I use the wireframe material to show that the text is indeed inside the cube. Also, the camera is positioned inside the cube - you can use arrows to move out.

#### Version 1.0.3

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box position="0 1.6 -0.5" material="wireframe: true" text="value: This is some text; color: green;" color="red"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

#### Version 1.1.0

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box position="0 1.6 -0.5" material="wireframe: true" text="value: This is some text; color: green;" color="red"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: That project was also being run on Glitch and I have started a new project on version 1.2.0 running it on a chromebook and a windows 10 computer and it works fine. So I guess it's an issue with Glitch.